# Why does this not return the IP address?

Tags: java, runtime

I can not get this to return anything but `null` for ip. I must be missing something in the way that I format the operations inside the String array, please help!  Also, is there a better sdk for command line work in Java? **Update** For future reference, this is an EC2 Instance, and doing an InetAddress.getLocalHost() returns null, so I've reverted to the command line (the AWS SDK is kind of a pain just to drill down for a localhost IP).

// Command to be run: `/sbin/ifconfig | awk 'NR==2{print$2}' | sed 's/addr://g'`

```
String[] command = new String[] {"/sbin/ifconfig", "awk 'NR==2{print$2}'", "sed 's/addr://g'" };
String ip = runCommand(command);

public static String runCommand(String[] command) {
        String ls_str;
        Process ls_proc = null;
        try {
            ls_proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        DataInputStream ls_in = new DataInputStream(ls_proc.getInputStream());

        try {
            while ((ls_str = ls_in.readLine()) != null) {
                    return ls_str;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Do you really have to resort to invoking a system command to get the IP addresses of your interfaces, or can you use Java libraries to do it?

Comment: It's an EC2 instance; the NetworkInterfaces don't seem to work.

Comment: @user375566 - I get output if I use code that enumerates the IP addresses in the system on my EC2 instances.

Comment: Weird.  InetAddress addr = null;
  try {
   addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
  } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

  String hostname = addr.getHostName();
  return hostname; returns null for me

Comment: ^They need a better way to format code inside comments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Why do you try to use `Runtime.exec()` when there's a [perfectly easy way to enumerate network interfaces in Java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getNetworkInterfaces%28%29)?
2. You try to execute multiple commands, piping one commands output onto the other one. That job is usually done by the shell. By directly executing it, you don't get that feature. You can work around that fact by invoking the shell and passing the whole pipe to it as an argument to be executed.
3. Read [When `Runtime.exec()` won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html). It summarizes all major pitfalls you can fall into when using `Runtime.exec()` (including the one mentioned in #2) and tells you how to avoid/solve them.

Comment: 1) The box is an EC2 instance; the NetworkInterfaces seems to return null.

Comment: #2 and #3 are still very valid :)

Comment: Agreed.  I've rarely have to do command line work in Java, good to know :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder()

    try {
        while ((ls_str = ls_in.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(ls_str);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result.toString();
```

Comment: That doesn't really matter as he's only interested in the first line anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass an array to exec(), it acts as if all the elements after the first are arguments to the first one.  "awk" is not a valid argument to `ifconfig`.

Answer (score 1):

The form of `Runtime.exec()` which takes a `String[]` does not execute multiple commands in a pipeline. Rather it executes a single command with additional arguments. I think the easiest way to do what you want is to `exec` a shell to do the pipeline:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { 
    "bash", "-c", "/sbin/ifconfig | awk 'NR==2{print$2}' | sed 's/addr://g'"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.net.NetworkInterface`. Like this:

```
public static List<String> getIPAdresses() {
    List<String> ips = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> e = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();

        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            NetworkInterface ni = e.nextElement();

            Enumeration<InetAddress> e2 = ni.getInetAddresses();

            while (e2.hasMoreElements()) {
                InetAddress ip = e2.nextElement();
                if (!ip.isLoopbackAddress())
                    ips.add(ip.getHostAddress());
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ips;
}
```

Joachim Sauer already posted the [link to the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getNetworkInterfaces%28%29)

Comment: I know how to do this; see the **update** for why I can't use this.